# Export a density plot as a columns and rows numbers

Tags: graphics, export

I have a `SmoothDensityHistogram` plot:

```
plot = Show[SmoothDensityHistogram[data,
   PlotRange -> {{0, 200}, {0, 200}}, Frame -> False], 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

[image: FPS]

which I would like to export to an indexed data file where each pixel is a number. How could I make it?

Thank you very much

Comment: [`ImageData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageData.html)?

Comment: @aardvark2012 Thanks. `ImageData` gives the three channel values of each pixel. but if I want to represent the image with only an array of values, and to reproduce the image select a colormap, how can I do it?

Comment: From the documentation, `SmoothDensityHistogram` "... generates colorized grayscale output of the PDF...", which _may_ mean that the lightness of the colour corresponds to the value you want. _If_ that's the case, you could get that value by some RBG colour formula, or with `ImageData[ColorConvert[image, "LAB"]][[All, All, 1]]` (which basically gives you the lightness components of all the pixels, ignoring hue and chroma).

Comment: Using  `SmoothKernelDistribution[data] /@ {"InterpolationPoints", "PDFValues"}` you can get the data needed to reconstruct the numbers underlying `SmoothDensityHistogram`.

Comment: [Documentation >>
 SmoothDensityHistogram](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SmoothDensityHistogram.html): _SmoothDensityHistogram effectively plots the distribution function of SmoothKernelDistribution_

Comment: Yes, or what @kglr said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `SmoothKernelDistribution` as, because as mentioned in Details section in docs, it is what is used for `SmoothDensityHistogram`:

```
R = 1.7;
SeedRandom[4];
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 10];
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[data]
```

and because you can sample it as a "matrix" raster this distribution at a desirable scale:

```
sample = Table[PDF[skd, {x, y}], {y, -R, R, scale}, {x, -R, R, scale}];
```

-- that's the pixels you need as I understand it. In Mathematica you can see them as

```
ArrayPlot[sample, ColorFunction -> "SolarColors", DataReversed -> True]
```

[image]

and export as for example

```
Export["sample.csv", sample]
```

`SmoothDensityHistogram` is not ideal for this as it formulates as Graphics object, in terms of polygons (that you could also extract as `InputForm[fig]` if needed):

```
fig = SmoothDensityHistogram[data,
    Mesh -> All,
    Epilog -> {Blue, PointSize[.02], Point[data]},
    ColorFunction -> "SolarColors", PlotRange -> {{-R, R}, {-R, R}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is what I pretend to make, and it works. I would also ask you if it would be possible to do the same but getting an array of `Intensity` or `Count` values as `DensityHistogram` can produce?

Comment: Is there a way to make the same but using `DensityHistobram[]` with option `Count`? Regards

Answer (score 4):

Using `SmoothKernelDistribution[data] /@ {"InterpolationPoints", "PDFValues"}` you can get the data needed to reconstruct the numbers underlying `SmoothDensityHistogram`.

[Documentation >> SmoothDensityHistogram](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SmoothDensityHistogram.html):

> *SmoothDensityHistogram* effectively plots the distribution function of *SmoothKernelDistribution*.

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 10];

{intpoints, values} = SmoothKernelDistribution[data] /@ 
   {"InterpolationPoints", "PDFValues"};
points = Tuples[intpoints];
data3D = Append @@@ Thread[{points, values}];
valuesdata = Transpose@Partition[values, Length[intpoints[[1]]]];
```

You can `Export` `valuesdata` or `data3D` which contains the set of 3D interpolation points and pdf values `{x, y, pdfvalue}` that underly `SmoothDensityHistogram`.

```
Row[Prepend[ListDensityPlot[#, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 300, 
     PlotLabel -> Style["ListDensityPlot - " <> #2, 16, "Panel"]] & @@@ 
    {{data3D, "data3D"}, {valuesdata, "valuesdata"}}, 
  SmoothDensityHistogram[data, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 300, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["SmoothDensityHistogram", 16, "Panel"]]]]
```

[image]

**Update:** *Is there a way to export the Count or Intensity values plotted with a DensityHistogram ?*

You can use

```
{bins, counts} = HistogramList[data, Automatic, "Count"]
```

to get the array of `counts`, and

```
intensities = HistogramList[data, List /@ bins, "Intensity"][[2]]
```

to get the array of `intensities` for the same bins.

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 500];
```

Using `"Count"` or  `counts&` as the third argument of `DensityHistogram` gives the same output:

```
{bins, counts} = HistogramList[data, Automatic, "Count"];
Row[{DensityHistogram[data, Automatic, "Count", ImageSize -> 300],  
   DensityHistogram[data, Automatic, counts&, ImageSize -> 300]}]
```

[image]

Similarly, using `"Intensity"` or  `intensitites&` as the third argument of `DensityHistogram` gives the same output:

```
intensities = HistogramList[data, List /@ bins, "Intensity"][[2]];
Row[{DensityHistogram[data, List /@ bins, "Intensity", ImageSize ->300],
  DensityHistogram[data, List /@ bins, intensities &, ImageSize -> 300]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Instead of `pdfvalues`, Is there a way to export the `Count` or `Intensity` values plotted with a `DensityHistogram` ? (instead `SmoothDensityHistogram`).

Comment: For `DensityHistogram` you can get the array of counts using `heights = HistogramList[data, Automatic, "Count"][[2]]`. Not sure how to get `Intensity`.

Comment: In version 11, `HistogramList[data, Automatic, "Intensity"][[2]]` works.

Comment: @user1993416, please see the update.

Comment: @klgr Thank you very much. I have tested with my image which has range 200x200 and extracting Counts and Intensities, and If I want to plot these arrays with `ArrayPlot` I get a different range of values which depend on bin value I assign. How can I keep the original plot xy ranges?

Comment: @user1993416, This sounds like a separate issue from your original question. I suggest you post a new question with a small example of the issue.

Comment: I have posted a new question in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155594/export-density-plot-counts-or-intensity-array-values

Answer (score 3):

Working from

```
image = your image saved as a jpeg
```

It's colour space (`ImageColorSpace[image]`) is RGB, so we'll want to convert to LAB:

```
id = ImageData[ColorConvert[image, "LAB"]][[All, All, 1]];
```

Which gives us an array of values. Plotting them using `ArrayPlot`:

```
ArrayPlot[1 - id]
```

[image]

So the data is still there, but I really have no idea how the lightness of the `ColorFunction` for `SmoothDensityHistogram` scales with the PDF, so I wouldn't pin too much on the accuracy of the numbers in `id` with respect to that PDF.