# Export Density plot Counts or Intensity array values

Tags: plotting, graphics, list-manipulation

I have the following code:

```
plot1 = Show[DensityHistogram[data, 100, "Count",
   PlotRange -> {{0, 200}, {0, 200}}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
   ChartLegends -> Automatic
   ], PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

[image]

which I would like to export as an array of numbers and reproduce the original image with `ArrayPlot` function. As the range is 200x200, the array should be of the same size to represent the whole range. Is there a way to get this array? This question is consequence of the precedent post  [Export a density plot as a columns and rows numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155560/export-a-density-plot-as-a-columns-and-rows-numbers/155573?noredirect=1#comment415296_155573)

Thank you for your help

Comment: whats wrong with `HistogramList` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{10, 10}, {5, 5}, .5], 1000];
```

You can use `HistogramList` using the same *binspec* you used in `DensityHistogram`  as the second argument:

```
{bins, heights} = HistogramList[data, 20]; 

Row[{dp = DensityHistogram[data, 20, "Count", ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
    Frame -> True,   ImageSize -> 400], 
  ArrayPlot[Reverse@Transpose@heights, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {Automatic, None}}, 
   DataRange -> PlotRange[dp], ColorRules -> {0 -> White}, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> 400]}]
```

[image]

Note the use of option [`DataRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DataRange.html) in `ArrayPlot`. Without it, `ArrayPlot` assumes the `x` and `y` values are row and column indices of the input array. The correct setting for this option can be obtained in several ways:

```
PlotRange[dp]
```

> {{-4., 26.}, {-6., 24.}}

```
PlotRange /. Options[dp, PlotRange]
```

> {{-4., 26.}, {-6., 24.}}

Or using `bins` obtained from `HistogramList`:

```
 MinMax /@ bins (* Through[{Min, Max}@#] & /@ bins for version 9 and earlier*)
```

> {{-4, 26}, {-6, 24}}

Comment: If I want to Export the array of count or intensity values but only a selected range, could I use `HistogramList[data,{0,200,20},"Count"]`?

Comment: @user1993416, i think it should work.